# Hidden or special characters in strings or different statement codes

Tags: c, string, fgets

How can I make my input string S1 of the fgets (or similar statement) to be equal to my declared static string S2?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main() {
    char s1[80];
    char s2[] = "This is a test.";
    int l1, l2;

    system("clear");
    printf("%s\n\n", s2);
    printf("Please type exactly the above sentence: ");
    fgets(s1,80,stdin);

    l1=strlen(s1);
    l2=strlen(s2);
    printf("\n String entered for S1, have a length of %d:\n %s", l1, s1);
    printf("\n String static  for S2, have a legnth of %d:\n %s", l2, s2);
    if(s1==s2)
        printf("\n\nOk! they're with the same length!\n");
    else
        printf("\n\nNop! They are NOT the same.\n");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Are you meaning to compare `l1` and `l2` rather than `s1` and `s2`?

Comment: I needed help to see why s1 and s2 where not the same string even when you have typed correctly the exact sentence "This is a test.".  And to seek how I could be able to make it so.  Thank you, and every one who have take the time (efforts) to look at this elemental issue.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgets` reads a line of input (up to a specified length, in your case 80). It stores that line in the array pointed to by its first argument (`s1`) -- including the terminating `'\n'` newline character.

Which means that after your `fgets` call, assuming you typed exactly `"This is a test."` and then typed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `s1` will contain `"This is a test.\n"`, *not* just `"This is a test."`.

You can remove that newline character before the comparison -- or rather you can replace it with a null character `'\0'`, which marks the end of the string:

```
size_t len = strlen(s1);
if (s1[len-1] == '\n') {
    s1[len-1] = '\0';
}
```

(You might need to move the declaration of `len` to the top of `main` if your compiler doesn't support mixed declarations and statements -- but the `strlen` call still has to be done *after* `fgets`.)

To test whether the `s1` and `s2` contain the same string value, use the `strcmp` function; your `s1 == s2` does a *pointer* comparison. `strcmp` returns 0 if the strings are equal. (If they're not, it returns a negative or positive value to indicate whether the left string is lexicographically less than or greater than the right string.)

Some minor comments on your code:

`main()` should be `int main(void)`. (Long story; for now, just take my word for it.)

There's probably no need to invoke `system("clear")`. Why do you want to clear the screen? There might be useful information on it. And it won't work on all systems. If I want to clear my screen before running your program, I can do it myself, thank you very much.

Your message "they're with the same length" isn't quite right. If you correct the test by using `strcmp` rather than `==`, you're testing whether the strings have the same value, whether their lengths happen to be the same or not.

Usually when you print a message, it's best to put the newline `\n` at the *end* of the output. It's usually best to have just a single `\n` at the end of the message (unless you want to print multiple lines with one `printf`, or build up one line with multiple `printf`s, which you can do but it's not necessary here.)

Your question originally had `gets` and `scanf` tags. Never use the `gets` function; it's inherently unsafe and has been removed from the language. `scanf` is tricky, and not needed in this case.

Comment: Good catch about the trailing newline.  I didn't catch it in my ideone fiddling because I didn't include the trailing newline in my input (so fgets would have instead returned because of EOF).

Comment: I have include the added "size_t" condition code for the character change from "\n" to "\0" for s1 (the entered string).  I also, modify the compared condition (s1==s2) using the statement "strcmp" instead comparing directly the pointers. And it did the job.  I also, followed the suggestions given by Mr. Thompson which I appreciated for our learning on making a efficient programming habit.  Case close!

Answer (score 5):

You're doing a pointer comparison, not a string comparison.  To compare the content of the strings, use [`strcmp` (docs)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html):

```
if (strcmp(s1, s2) == 0)
...
```